# Запятая перед тире

Tags: пунктуация

Не то чтобы я шарил в этих делах — дома-то у меня телевизор никогда не стоял**,** — **но** знал наверняка: наш посёлок не представлял культурной ценности, только вид с горы радовал глаз.

Правильно?

По такому правилу:  «Если же вставная конструкция выделяется тире, то ставит сочетание знаков (запятая и затем тире): Он встал и, прихрамывая — он был на протезе, — прошёл к окну (В. Каве­рин) (запятая закрывает обособленное обстоятельство, выраженное одиночным деепричастием)».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё правильно. 
В обоих случаях с помощью тире  обособляется вставная конструкция,  а запятая перед вторым тире является "перенесенной".